# How to go to the "root" directory of a website?

Tags: php

There is a PHP website into a Linux computer webserver. In a particular PHP file , which is located in a deep subdirectory of this site , I want to go to the first directory of the site. How to write the PHP code to achieve that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "go to" the directory? Are you looking to redirect the user's browser to the URL `http://yoursite.com/`, link to there, change the PHP script's working directory, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will respond the filesystem path to http://your_hostname/

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

[Documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

this will give the root directory.